# How to convert an object from class to superclass

Tags: java, class, inheritance

I have to model breakwater that controls permissions in certain coast. My solution implements a class "Ship" and classes "OilShip", "FishingShip" and "CarriageShip", I used inheritance and made

```
public class OilShip extends Ship{
 ...
} 
public class FishingShip extends Ship{
 ...
}
public class CarriageShip extends Ship{
 ...
}
```

In another class I have Ship ship=new Ship(...); and I'd like to somehow make an Oilship into Ship, i.e.

```
public Class Abcd{
  Ship ship;

  public Abcd(OilShip oship){
  ship=oship; //*************
  }
}
```

There seems to be a problem with the code, please tell me.

Comment: That will work fine.  What problem are you having?

Comment: Can you explain your problem?If you are using IDE, did you get any error or warnings on screen?If you are are using command line to compile the java classes, did you get any compilation error?

Comment: The code you added will make the member `ship` in `class abcd` point to an instance of an oil_ship via the ship class interface.

You stated that you have an instance of a ship `Ship ship=new Ship(...);` this instance will never be an oil_ship

Comment: I'm working on Netbeans, and when I try to do that it says "incompatible types: oil_ship cannot be converted to Ship"

Comment: Then oil_ship doesn't extend Ship. Or it extends another Ship class, in a different package. Please respect the Java naming conventions: classes are CamelCase. Your classes should be named `OilShip`, `FishingShip` and `CarriageShip`.

Comment: Is there another way to do this? I mean, the idea is that objects of type abcd need to be created for different kinds of ships. So I though the best way of doing this to reduce redundancy (I'm not an expert) is to create 3 constructures in abcd, each of which recieves as parameter a different kind of ship and then convert them to a "generic" type (Ship).

Comment: Get the object a bodysuit with a big "S" on the front.

Comment: @Hot Licks can you explain that? thanks.

Comment: http://images4.fanpop.com/image/photos/20400000/Publicity-Photo-superman-the-movie-20409106-1054-1400.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you call the superclass' constructor inside your subclasses' constructors.

This solution works fine for me:

```
public class Ship {
    private String name;
    private int weight;

    public Ship(String name, int weight) {
        this.name = name;
        this.weight = weight;
    }
}

class OilShip extends Ship {
    private int oilCapacity;

    public OilShip(int oilCapacity, String name, int weight) {
        super(name, weight);
        this.oilCapacity = oilCapacity;
    }
}

class FishingShip extends Ship {
    private int fisherMen;

    public FishingShip(int fisherMen, String name, int weight) {
        super(name, weight);
        this.fisherMen = fisherMen;
    }
}

class CarriageShip extends Ship {
    private int containers;

    public CarriageShip(int containers, String name, int weight) {
        super(name, weight);
        this.containers = containers;
    }
}
```

**As mentioned before, Java-classes should always be given a name, where the first character is in UPPERCASE and the same with each new word --> CamelCase**

You don't need different constructors. The awesome thing behind using inheritance here, is, that no matter what subclass from the superclass "Ship" you put into your constructor in "abcd", it will be accepted:

```
public class Abcd {
    private Ship ship;

    public Abcd(Ship ship){
        this.ship = ship;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, CamelCase is already corrected. I'd like to have somethig like this:

     `public Abcd(OilShip oship){
            this.ship = oship;
     }`

Or something like that. Is that impossible?